# Convert an Observable to an async generator

Tags: rxjs, babeljs, ecmascript-next, reactive

I'm trying to use rxjs in conjunction with babeljs to create an async generator function that yields when `next` is called, throws when `error` is called, and finishes when `complete` is called.  The problem I have with this is that I can't yield from a callback.

I can `await` a Promise to handle the return/throw requirement.

```js
async function *getData( observable ) {
    await new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {
        observable.subscribe( {
            next( data ) {
                yield data; // can't yield here
            },
            error( err ) {
                reject( err );
            },
            complete() {
                resolve();
            }
        } );
    } );
}

( async function example() {
    for await( const data of getData( foo ) ) {
        console.log( 'data received' );
    }
    console.log( 'done' );
}() );
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I asked the rubber duck, then I wrote the following code which does what I wanted:

```js
function defer() {
    const properties = {},
        promise = new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {
            Object.assign( properties, { resolve, reject } );
        } );
        return Object.assign( promise, properties );
}

async function *getData( observable ) {
    let nextData = defer();
    const sub = observable.subscribe( {
        next( data ) {
            const n = nextData;
            nextData = defer();
            n.resolve( data );
        },
        error( err ) {
            nextData.reject( err );
        },
        complete() {
            const n = nextData;
            nextData = null;
            n.resolve();
        }
    } );
    try {
        for(;;) {
            const value = await nextData;
            if( !nextData ) break;
            yield value;
        }
    } finally {
        sub.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think a problem with this solution is that the observable could generate several values in one batch (without deferring). This is my proposal:

```js
const defer = () => new Promise (resolve =>
    setTimeout (resolve, 0));

async function* getData (observable)
{
    let values = [];
    let error = null;
    let done = false;
    observable.subscribe (
        data => values.push (data),
        err => error = err,
        () => done = true);
    for (;;)
    {
        if (values.length)
        {
            for (const value of values)
                yield value;
            values = [];
        }
        if (error)
            throw error;
        if (done)
            return;
        await defer ();
    }
}
```